# Django delete object which has a string as a primary key

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following model

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(Person, primary_key=True)
    room = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=12)
```

When I run the following code I get the error `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'lacc1'`

```
s = Staff.objects.get(pk = 'lacc1').delete()
```

I assume this has something to do with the primary key being a string.  Does anyone know how I can solve this problem.

It is only on deletes.  If I just want to get the object using get or filter it works fine. There is also a object in the db with pk `lacc1` so that is not the problem.

EDIT

Person Class

```
class Person(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    forenames = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Can you also post your Person class?

Comment: Does deleting from the Django Admin work?

Answer (score 3):

**Your primary key is not a string, it's an int.**

```
username = models.OneToOneField(Person, primary_key=True)
```

`username` here is not a `CharField` but a `OneToOneField`, meaning a relation to a `Person` object model, meaning a field containing the id of the row of this person instance in the person table.

You may want to rename it this way:

```
person = models.OneToOneField(Person, primary_key=True)
```

And, assuming your `Person` object has a `username`attribute, you can delete your staff this way:

```
s = Staff.objects.get(person__username='lacc1').delete()
```

However, you must know that this implies a `JOIN` on the `person_id` field and a filter on a the Staff `username` field, which is probably not indexed. It will be slower than what you expected, but I doubt it should ba any trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work.  I have no problem getting the objects, its just when I try to call the delete() method.  So s = Staff.objects.get(person__username='lacc1') would give me the object but as soon as I call the delete method on the object I get the error.

Comment: Delete you database, rerun syncdb then create your objects using the django admin. You should not have a Staff object with a primary key being 'lacc1'. I can't guess what you made to create it, but it does not match your model.